# bash Scripting for iterating on specific directories in the target file path and ignoring certain directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently using the below bash script snippet to iterate over all directories in the path **dirName**

```
dirName="file-path/folder-name"

for dir in $(ls -d */); do
    dirName=${dir%/}

    pid=`cat $parentDir/$dirName/$dirName.lck`

    if [ -n "$pid" ]
    then
            printf "$dirName : RUNNING \n"

    fi

    cd ..
done
```

I need to implement the same above logic, but the only change is to iterate only on certain directories and excluding some directories in the given path.

Request help on this as I am trying to figure out the alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious problems here; `ls` is not only useless, but [actively problematic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); and running `cd ..` repeatedly inside the loop definitely looks like an error. Well, three; you have not initialized `parentDir`.

In addition to that, it's easy to add a skip.

```sh
parentDir="something here, surely?"
dirName="file-path/folder-name"

for dir in ./*/; do
    case $dir in
        ./foo | ./bar | *covfefe* ) continue;;
    esac

    dirName=${dir%/}

    # Fix quoting; prefer modern command substitution syntax over backticks
    pid=$(cat "$parentDir/$dirName/$dirName.lck")

    if [ -n "$pid" ]
    then
        # Format string problem -- pass directory as argument
        printf "%s: RUNNING\n" "$dirName"
    fi
done
```

Comment: $parentDir is not initialiazed

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `ls`

```
for dir in */; do
  echo "$dir"
done
```

If you want to strip the pathname.

```
"${dir##*/}"
```

change the echo t something else, things that you want to do with the directories.

Answer (score 0):

You could use find to iterate just what you need, like this

```
dirName="file-path/folder-name"
for D in $(find $dirName -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path "./dir-to-exclude/*" ! -path "./other-dir-to-exclude" );do
    echo "$D"
done
```

The -path option, together with the negation flag (!), will skip what you need to skip

**EDIT**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path "./dir-to-exclude" ! -path "./other-dir-to-exclude" -exec sh -c 'for file do echo "$file";done' sh {} +
```

I edited the command, after triplee suggestion, to avoid unescaped blanks or shell special characters in dirnames, that could break the code

Comment: You have two levels of quoting problems here. Fixing `echo "$D"` is easy but too late to fix the `for` loop. To just print the file names correctly, obviously, simply use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path "./dir-to-exclude/*" ! -path "./other-dir-to-exclude"`. For operating on those files, look into `find ... -exec` as the safest and most robust solution.

Comment: Thanks for the echo issue, fixed now. Using -exec in find is ok, but it depends on how complex the operation you want to perform to each directory is. It could be convenient, or not. In the question the user is doing too many things to put all of them in the -exec parameter

Comment: Not at all; there is no limit. Simply `-exec sh -c 'lots of things; more stuff; etc' \;` if you have complex shell commands you want to run in there.

Comment: The main problem here is if `find` returns a file name which contains whitespace or other shell metacharacters. There is no quoting (and it can't be added after the fact); so the shell will interpret those metacharacters. See also https://dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is those files `*.lck` right? Then try this approach.

```
path=some/path

IFS=$'\n'; for file in $(find "$path" -type f -name *.lck); {
    pid=$(cat "$file")
    # i assume that it's better to check that $pid actually exists
    [[ -e $pid ]] && echo "$(dirname $file) : RUNNING"
}
```

Or using grep

```
while IFS=: read name pid; do
    [[ -e $pid ]] && echo "$(dirname $name) : RUNNING"
done <<< $(grep -re [[:digit:]] "$path"/*.lck)
```